# CSS Style First Row and Column

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, row, col

How can I use CSS to make the first row and column of a table not have a border?

I can get the first column to work, but not the first row.

Below is my code:

```
#tablegrid tr:not(:nth-child(1)), td:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

<table id="tablegrid">
<TR>
  <TD>row 1 col 1</TD>
  <TD>row 1 col 2</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD>row 2 col 1</TD>
  <TD>row 2 col 2</TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wj6k0ta/

Comment: Use the CSS first-child selector. Follow the link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector should be

```
tr:not(:nth-child(1)) td
```

That selects every `<td>` element in every row other than the first row.

If you want *all* the first cells to not have a border, I'd add a separate rule:

```
#tablegrid tr td:first-child {
  border-style: none;
}
```

That should go after the first rule of course.

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  Will check as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr:first-child` to take the first `tr` of a table